# empty exception occurs while adding a task to taskqueue, but the task gets added and executed successfully

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am creating task using taskqueue.add inside try-except block.
It is going to except block, which means that error happening while creating task using taskqueue.add.
But, No error message is returned and also task is created successfully.
So, An empty exception occurs while adding a task to task queue, but the task does get added successfully and also gets executed as expected.
Why task is created when error is happened, and what is the meaning of empty exception?

If error happens while adding a task then task should not be added and can someone confirm if an empty exception is retruned then tasks are added successfully always?

Comment: You are going to have to give us some more information than this.  Perhaps some reproducible code.  Adding a task to a task queue should not ordinarily cause an exception.

Comment: I repeat what I said earlier.  You're going to have to give us more information.